# Android Admob ads services update

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

I recently have received an email update that AdMob will stop serving ads on 17 Oct 2016 to the SDK versions listed in this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android-legacy-release-notes and has to be amended to one included in this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/release-notes#android

I am currently using Android Eclipse and was generating ads by the library GooglePlayServices, with codes as follows:

### Code:

[image]

[image]

### Question:

How could I check the GooglePlayServices library version? I opened the Android SDK Manager and found no updates of GooglePlayServices library is available.

How could I ensure Admob implementation is ok for ads to continue? Is the prerequisite necessary for Admob ads? I am still using Eclipse.

- Running Android Studio 1.0 or higher
- Developing for Android level 9 or higher
- An Android Studio project

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39418244/upgrade-your-android-google-mobile-ads-sdk-to-ensure-ads-keep-serving/39422371#39422371

Comment: if you are using GooglePlayServices Library > 4. You are good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

search for version.xml inside your google-play-services_lib

```
<integer name="google_play_services_version">4323000</integer>
```

find detail explanation here [Upgrade your Android Google Mobile Ads SDK to ensure ads keep serving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39418244/upgrade-your-android-google-mobile-ads-sdk-to-ensure-ads-keep-serving/39422371#39422371)

Comment: Please have a look at this link :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39463150/ads-mob-sdk-updation-in-eclipse?noredirect=1#comment66246934_39463150