# Check Android Admob SDK version

Tags: android, admob

I found this email from Google:

> Hi AdMob Publisher, In early July, we sent out a notice to AdMob
>   Publishers who have apps running on SDK version 6.4.1 and lower, to
>   inform them about deprecating SDK versions and the need to upgrade by
>   September 15, 2016.

Is it possible to detect what version of SDK in my APK file is used? What is the easest way to know this version in the old project?

Comment: By checking your project's `gradle.properties` file ?

Comment: I'm useing eclipse project

Comment: please check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39424525/android-admob-ads-services-update

Comment: @AmodGokhale ,thanks