# Ads Mob Sdk updation in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, admob

I just received email from Google that on 17th oct on-wards they will stop displaying ads as the methods got deprecated.I also studied about it on some links as follows :-

https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples

The above is GitHub link , the sample provided by Google with new SDK , as that is for android -studio , as my applications are already in market from past 2 years. So Do I need to migrate my whole project to Android studio ?  Or is there some way to do updation in eclipse ?

I also Found a link which states that if we are using Google Play services with version higher that 4 then our ads will not get effected by Google

Here is the link :- [Upgrade your Android Google Mobile Ads SDK to ensure ads keep serving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39418244/upgrade-your-android-google-mobile-ads-sdk-to-ensure-ads-keep-serving/39422371#39422371)

Here is my Google Play Service version detail :-

```
 android:versionCode="5089000" 
android:versionName="5.0.89-000"
```

Method i am using to get Ads :-

```
private void getAds() {
    try {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .addTestDevice("").build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        adView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In My XML :-

```html
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="YOUR KEy"
            android:background="@drawable/container_ads_bg" />
```

**Please Have a look at this link too** :-

https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/existing-app

This shows that this can be done in eclipse too.

The thing is **my code is pretty old its almost 3 years old** so i am little afraid in migrating it , but if i have no other option left with me then i will surely migrate it.

So do I need to update the SDK  and Configure it with FireBase ?

Please let me know ,as we have very less time left to update the SDK.

Thanks.

Comment: Migrating to Android Studio is pretty easy. Android Studio provides project import function from Eclipse. Try to use Android Studio, you will love it and never go back to Eclipse.

Comment: it's good idea to update to latest Android Studio and firebase version so that your mobile app has latest library etc.. But to answer your question Is it mandatory to update ?- no you don't need to update SDK or even configure with Firebase. Your existing app will continue to run without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest migrate to Android Studio and use **inbuilt utility of adMob and Firebase**

In your case, please import your project into Android studio, it will suggest, ways to update project with latest SDKs.